# Removing Fancy pagestyle header

Tags: fancyhdr

How can I make it so that the header text and header line disappear on pages where a new section starts, i.e. when I use `\section`? To be clear, I would like to footer to remain, so `\fancyhf{}` does not work.

Comment: \thispagestyle{plain} as opposed to \thispagestyle{empty}

Comment: @JohnKormylo almost -- can I keep the line at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a fancy page style, by:

```
\fancypagestyle{sectionpage}{
    \fancyfoot{your footer}
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt)% or however thick
}
```

Then for each new section use `\thispagestyle{sectionpage}`.

After *this page* (the first of the section), it'll revert to whatever `\fancyfoot`/`head` (and rule widths) you have defined for the general document.

Comment: This puts "your footer" on the left, center, and right. How can use the center footer only?

Comment: You can specify location of the footer either (or all) of L,C,R as `\fancyfoot[L]{your footer}`. Also, if you want some footer/header styles to be L only, others to be different, it's helpful to first refresh the respective styles by adding a blank def first, then one with what you want - when you define it. (Like `\fancypagestyle{sectionpage}{ \fancyfoot{}\fancyfoot[L]{your footer}, etc.}`

Comment: It appears that entirely removing the '\fancyfoot' command restores the original footer I had in place, so that accidentally fixes the problem. Thanks for the words of wisdom!